# opam fails to install snappy.0.1.0

Tags: linux, ocaml, opam

I am currently trying to install `snappy.0.1.0` through OPAM but I am getting these errors:

```
support@ubuntu-template:~$ sudo opam install snappy.0.1.0
[WARNING] Running as root is not recommended
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗  install snappy 0.1.0

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[snappy] Archive in cache

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[ERROR] The compilation of snappy failed at "ocaml setup.ml -build".
Processing  1/1: [snappy: ocamlfind remove]
#=== ERROR while installing snappy.0.1.0 ======================================#
# opam-version 1.2.2
# os           linux
# command      ocaml setup.ml -build
# path         /home/support/.opam/4.02.1/build/snappy.0.1.0
# compiler     4.02.1
# exit-code    1
# env-file     /home/support/.opam/4.02.1/build/snappy.0.1.0/snappy-26159-58c514.env
# stdout-file  /home/support/.opam/4.02.1/build/snappy.0.1.0/snappy-26159-58c514.out
# stderr-file  /home/support/.opam/4.02.1/build/snappy.0.1.0/snappy-26159-58c514.err
### stdout ###
# /home/support/.opam/4.02.1/bin/ocamlopt.opt unix.cmxa -I /home/support/.opam/4.02.1/lib/ocaml/ocamlbuild /home/support/.opam/4.02.1/lib/ocaml/ocamlbuild/ocamlbuildlib.cmxa myocamlbuild.ml /home/support/.opam/4.02.1/lib/ocaml/ocamlbuild/ocamlbuild.cmx -o myocamlbuild
# ocamlfind ocamlc -ccopt -x -ccopt c++ -c src/snappy_stubs.c
# + ocamlfind ocamlc -ccopt -x -ccopt c++ -c src/snappy_stubs.c
# gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
# Command exited with code 2.
### stderr ###
# File "setup.ml", line 213, characters 8-26:
# Warning 3: deprecated: String.set
# Use Bytes.set instead.
# File "setup.ml", line 1793, characters 6-24:
# Warning 3: deprecated: Lazy.lazy_from_fun
# Use Lazy.from_fun instead.
# E: Failure("Command ''/home/support/.opam/4.02.1/bin/ocamlbuild' src/libsnappy_stubs.a src/dllsnappy_stubs.so src/snappy.cma src/snappy.cmxa src/snappy.a src/snappy.cmxs test.native -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")



    =-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    The following actions failed
      ∗  install snappy 0.1.0
    No changes have been performed

    =-=- snappy.0.1.0 troobleshooting -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    => This package relies on external (system) dependencies that may be missing. `opam depext snappy.0.1.0' may help you find the correct installation for your system.

=-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
The following actions failed
  ∗  install snappy 0.1.0
No changes have been performed

=-=- snappy.0.1.0 troobleshooting -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
=> This package relies on external (system) dependencies that may be missing. `opam depext snappy.0.1.0' may help you find the correct installation for your system.
```

When trying to install the missing dependencies:

```
support@ubuntu-template:~$ sudo opam depext snappy.0.1.0
# Detecting depexts using flags: x86_64 linux ubuntu
# The following system packages are needed:
#  - libsnappy-dev
#  - m4
# All required OS packages found.
```

Still having the error after retrying.

Comment: It looks like your C++ compiler is missing. Try `sudo apt-get install g++`.

Comment: Did the trick! I already installed `gcc` so I thought that would do the trick...